# Persistent diagrams for images : existing implementations or packages?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, computational-geometry, data-analysis, computational-topology

I am interest to compute the persistent diagram associated to the image of a persistent module as in ''Persistent Homology for Kernels, Images, and Cokernels'' : https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/1.9781611973068.110

Roughly, the setting is the following :  let two tame functions, $f: \mathbb{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{Y} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a subspace $\mathbb{Y} \subseteq \mathbb{X}$. We suppose that $f(y) \leq g(y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{Y} \subseteq \mathbb{X}$. We order the collection of critical values of $f$ and $g$ and interleave them with a sequence of real values $(s_i)_{1,\ldots,m}$. We denote $\mathbb{X}_i=f^{-1}\left(-\infty, s_i\right]$ and $\mathbb{Y}_i=g^{-1}\left(-\infty, s_i\right]$. The two sequences are connected by homomorphisms $j_i: \mathrm{H}\left(\mathbb{Y}_i\right) \rightarrow$ $\mathrm{H}\left(\mathbb{X}_i\right)$ induced by the inclusions $\mathbb{Y}_i \subseteq \mathbb{X}_i$. The goal is to compute the persistent diagram (or barcode) of,
$$\operatorname{Im}(g \rightarrow f) \quad: \quad \operatorname{im} j_0 \rightarrow \operatorname{im} j_1 \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow \operatorname{im} j_m$$
where,
$$
\operatorname{im} j_i=\{j_i(\gamma) \in \mathrm{H}\left(\mathbb{X}_i\right) | \gamma \in \mathrm{H}\left(\mathbb{Y}_i\right)\}
$$

This paper provides (in Section 3) an algorithm to do so (up to some approximation by simplicial complex). Do an existing implementation of this algorithm (or a similar one) is available somewhere ? I am working with Python.